# OrientDB - Limit by time or prevent huge queries execution

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Is there a way to limit a query execution by time? 
I'm familiar with the `TIMEOUT` clause of a `SELECT` statement, but I can't seem to find an equivalent for the graph queries, such as `MATCH` or `TRAVERSE`.

An alternative for a timeout will be to identify somehow the problematic query and avoid it, but I can't find any `EXPLAIN` statement to perform without actually perform the query...

The situation is quite problematic as performing 2-3 `MATCH` queries may explore the whole graph, take forever to complete and only hard-reset releases them.

I've also searched for an option to cancel/interrupt/kill a query but couldn't find it (only via HTTP API).

We're using the JAVA API with version 2.2.30.

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is to upgrade to 3.0.x that has a new Query executor and query planner. And a very useful EXPLAIN command as well. 2.0.30 is quite old, AFAIK

Comment: Thanx @RobertoFranchini we do have a plan to upgrade to 3.x and we're very excited about it :) However, now, we need to seek for a solution still on 2.2.x